# XMPP/Jabber web-based clients

Tags: web, client-side, xmpp

What are the web-based clients for XMPP/Jabber. I need run IM client in browser (Windows/Linux FF2-8, Opera 10+, IE 6(?)-8).

I found only one SparkWeb - http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/sparkweb/index.jsp

Is this the only one?

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: Better suited for superuser perhaps?

Comment: Actually for http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Getting a gold badge for a closed off-topic question should be honoured with platin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's [a list of clients on xmpp.org](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/), that includes browser based clients.  (Those with *Browser* in the platform column.)